# Is GC Broken on RPi Pico

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am using the latest stable release of micropython and below is my entire program.

```py
import gc
gc.collect()
print('free:{}, alloc:{}'.format(gc.mem_free(), gc.mem_alloc()))
#free:187488, alloc:4576
```

Where did 64k of my RAM go? I know it isn't a hardware issue. I plugged in a brand new Pico that doesn't even have headers soldered on it, and got the exact same results. Am I missing something?

EDIT:

I found the below in `ports/rp2/main.c`. Is there some reason why it's not `256`?

```c
static char gc_heap[192 * 1024];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that 64kb of RAM are automatically allocated to fit the `firmware.elf`. So, not only do you not actually get 264k of RAM (due to Hypervisor using 8k), but you don't get 256k of RAM either. Changing the edit in my question to:

```c
static char gc_heap[256 * 1024];
```

leads to these messages:

```
firmware.elf section '.bss' will not fit in region 'RAM' 
region 'RAM' overflowed by 40848 bytes
```

Conclusion: There are only 192kb of usable RAM on a Raspberry Pi Pico that utilizes micropython.